Import Error with "data-structure-typed" Library in Node.js
I am encountering an import error when using the data-structure-typed package in my Node.js application. While importing specific components like Queue directly works fine, attempting to import the entire library causes issues. Here's a brief overview of the problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-structure-typed
I'm using Node.js v20.11.1 and the data-structure-typed library version 1.51.9. My project setup is as follows:
{
  "name": "playbook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "data-structure-typed": "^1.51.9",
    "queue-typed": "^1.51.9"
  }
}

The error occurs when I try to import the Queue class from the library like this:
import { Queue } from "data-structure-typed";

The terminal throws this error:
SyntaxError: The requested module 'data-structure-typed' does not provide an export named 'Queue'

Could someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried various methods such as dynamic imports, using CommonJS modules, etc., but nothing seems to work.
